# Is there a video format equivalent to .svg for images?

Tags: xml, html, video, svg, html5-video

Is there a format, experimental or otherwise, that uses a video equivalent to Scaled Vector Graphics?

It needn't be XML. What I mean is a script-based video format. Something that, like SVG, allows high compressibility, compared to raster format, particularly for cartoon-style videos. That is those made up of simple elements, rather than rich formats.

I understand that SVG 2.0 is supposed to support HTML5, so that would allow something like that. Is that correct?

If so, are there applications that would allow the export of videos, with sound, in that format?

Comment: What's wrong with SVG itself? It can be animated using SMIL.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with SVG, or its animation. However, what I'm actually wanting to do, is produce training courses, based on screenshots (the sort QuickTime produces), that are small enough to send through e-mail. So I need a synchronised audio track, and a video that's 10 minutes to 40 minutes long.

Comment: You could synchronise the audio track using SMIL events. There's lots of alternatives such as WebGL about though.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I see quite a few things. I'm having difficulty, though, seeing how to get the .mov -> SVG-style. I've tried setting H.264 as the codec to produce a .m4v file and it has taken a .mov file of 11.9Mb to 7.7Mb, but the quality's not that good. I'll have to try it with a bigger file.

Comment: The thing that I find good about .svg, is that it's easy to modify the file either manually, or with a simple conversion script, to get the effect desired. This doesn't allow that. Conversion programs like Handbrake and VideoConverter don't seem to offer a conversion to WebGL or OpenGL or HTML5 - this conversion to H.264 in a .m4v container seems the closest I can get to that, but it's far from transparent!

Answer (score 2):

I've found an excellent solution:

Miro Video Converter (Free & Open Source) has converted my 12:55 minute Quicktime .mov file of 407MB to a .webm file of only 39.1MB. It plays perfectly with first rate resolution - it is possible to read all the text on the screen perfectly, with no distortion. The Quicktime resolution was 2880x1800.

Interestingly, the paid for closed source program VideoConverterUltimate can also convert to .webm, but produces a file of 124.3 MB - so that's not a good solution.

The .webm file plays back in Firefox and VLC. Obviously old-fashioned browsers like IE won't work, but no surprise there.

The .webm format is a free and open video format designed to provide royalty-free high-quality video compression for use with HTML5 video.

Strangely, the video doesn't play in Google Chrome - the audio works, but the film has gone, and is replaced by some Chinese text.. particularly odd as the format is supposed to be designed for google chrome. Anyway, it works with Firefox and VLC, who'd want more?

Video

Codec: Google/On2's VP8 Video (VP80)

Resolution: 1080x674

Frame Rate: 60.002400

Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV

Audio

Codec: Vorbis Audio (vorb)

Sample rate: 44100 Hz

Bitrate 112 kb/s

Encoder: Lavc54.23.100